# Safe to release UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am creating a (UIPopoverController) popover controller and (UINavigationController) navigation controller for the popover, where both controllers are declared in the header file.  Then, when they are created:

```
myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[MyPopoverControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopoverNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease]];

myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myNavController];
```

At this point, is it safe to release myNavController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may release your navigation controller after initializing your popover controller if this class isn't going to refer to it again.

Comment: In the MyPopoverControllerClass, I call pushViewController on myNavController after it is created and the user clicks on an item that is displayed on the popover...so should I not release the myNavController here?

Answer (score 1):

If `myNavController` is an instance variable, then you shouldn't release it until your `dealloc` method. If it's just a local variable, you should release it after the last reference to it in that method.

Comment: Exactly; if you have a retained reference, you "own" the object.  If that reference is no longer needed, you should release it.   If it is an instance variable and you are `release`ing outside of `dealloc`, it is also a good idea to assign `nil` to the instance variable so you don't end up with a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about [Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB) convention which briefly says that if you've alloc'ed an object, you are its owner.

In other words, you are in all rights to release `myNavController` as soon as you don't need it.

From another side, `UIPopoverController` should take ownership over `myNavController` using retain.

So, (again) yes. You can safely release `myNavController`.

There are some rare situations when ownership convention rules not respected. These kind of exceptions are mentioned in documentation for specific methods. But here is not the case.

Lets apply these rules for your snippet:
In the first line

```
  myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[[MyPopoverControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopoverNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease]];
```

retain count for `myNavController` is **at least** 1.

The second line

```
myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myNavController];
```

will result in retain count for  `myNavController` to be **at least** 2, through ownership taken inside `initWithContentViewController`.

Comment: Do *not* call `retainCount`.  Given that `UIPopoverController` is a class from the UIKit framework, the retain count at any given time is entirely an implementation detail.  Trying to assign meaning to an absolute value is futile.   Think of retains entirely as ownership and deltas;  if you no longer need to own an object, you release it.

Comment: @bbum: `UIPopoverController` inherits from `NSObject`, so it's ok to pass `retainCount` message. Expressions I've used here like `[x retainCount]` are purely illustrative, and have meaning that an object have **at least** this value. And please, show me what exactly I'm trying to assign ?

Comment: You said "will result in retain count for myNavController to be 2". That is a wrong assumption.  It is not ok to pass retainCount and expect a given absolute value.   It is bad (incorrect) advice on an other wise correct answer

Comment: Ok, updated the answer with corresponding remarks. I've just tried to explain the main idea as simple as it could be.